# Regex based string split in Java

Tags: java, regex

```
String delimiterRegexp = "(;|:|[^<]/)";
String value = "get/time/pick me <i>Jack</i>";
String[] splitedTexts = value.split(delimiterRegexp);
for (String text : splitedTexts) {
System.out.println(text);
}

Output:
ge
tim
pick me <i>Jack</i>

Expected Result: 
get
time
pick me <i>Jack</i>
```

A character is getting added as delimeter along with /. Could anyone help me out to write regex to split text based on delimeter"/" and it should ignore xml end tag"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^<]/` will match `e/` and `t/`

use a lookbehind instead, it will have the wanted behaviour to only consider `/` as separator if it's not a closing tag

On [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HU1Fuz/1)

```
(?<!<)/
```

The whole regex

```
(;|:|(?<!<)/)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex should be like this:

```
(;|:|(?<!<)/)
```

with a negative lookbehind, demo: https://regex101.com/r/2k1WI5/1/

Your current regex `[^<]/` will match basically any character that is not `<` followed by `/` even `\n`, space, and Japanese characters.

That's why you are losing some letters as they are considered as part of the separator.

Following [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) recommendation, you can even simplify the regex into: `([;:]|(?<!<)/)`

Comment: Perhaps you could also reduce the first alternation to `([;:]|(?<!<)/)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird:
Thanks! It's even more beautiful!